# Why is $igF_{\mu\nu}:=[D_\mu,D_\nu]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, covariance, quantum-field-theory

Asking from a mathematical perspective (as opposed to a physical one):

Why is the field strength tensor defined to be the commutator of covariant derivatives? I understand the general intuition behind it (the Lie Bracket gives the difference in “flow” in directions, and the covariant derivative tells how the field changes), but I’m looking for a rigorously mathematical perspective.

I have experience with some differential geometry and Lie Algebras.

Comment: Are you familiar with principal bundles? The computation you wanna see boils down to using "local coodinates" (i.e. a choice of local gauge) and expanding. The double derivative terms cancel out if you assume enough smoothness, leaving you with the usual field strength. The tools can all be found in Hamiltons "Mathematical gauge theory".

Comment: I am not familiar with principal bundles. Do you have any pointers towards good resources for learning these? Thank you for the reference to the book.

Comment: The book I recommended is a very good resource, especially as an introductory text. Otherwise, there are no good "monographs" on gauge theory that I am aware of. A lof o textbooks have chapters on gauge theory, so does Nakahars book "Differential geometry, topology and physics".

Comment: Okay. I meant more specifically vector bundles/fibers. I’ve looked over the definitions but have been unsure where to start to learn about them. I’m assuming some sort of topology?

Comment: It's hard for me to see what you're looking for. A mathematician might start with an intuitive idea like the one you cite, compute the commutator of the covariant derivatives, and see what they get. In this specific situation, the commutator of the partial derivatives of a function vanishes, because partial derivatives commute. Once you have defined the covariant derivative of a vector field, it is natural to ask what the commutator is.

Answer (score 0):

I think for now I will answer with an example: You can generalize all this by working on principal bundles, connection 1-forms, local gauges and chosing representations accordingly.
Let $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $G=SU(2)$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and let $\phi:M \to \mathbb{C}^2$ be a smooth function. $SU(2)$ acts by right-multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$. Then let us chose a "connection $1$-form"/gauge potential of the form $A_i=t^aA^a_i$ (may depend on $x\in M$) and define the covariant derivative to be
$$
D_i=\partial_i+A_i
$$
Now, let us calculate
\begin{align*}
[D_i,D_j]\phi &=\partial_i\partial_j \phi-\partial_j\partial_i \phi+A_iA_j\phi-A_jA_i\phi + \partial_i A_j \phi-\partial_jA_i \\
&=[A_i,A_j]\phi+ \partial_i A_j \phi-\partial_jA_i \\
&=F_{ij}\phi
\end{align*}
This works for any smooth $\phi$, since partial derivatives commute. The extra factor of $ig$ is usually a consequence of conventions.
The major simplifications we made are

1)We have a globally defined gauge potential
2)The codomain of $\phi$ is a nice, well known space with a simple representation of $G$ (instead of e.g. a Lie algebra)
3)We use "global coordinates", one of the major advantages of working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and having a global gauge potential
4)Every object has an interpretation without using sections of this and that bundle.

If you were to work on (associated) vector bundles $E$ equipped with the a covariant derivative $\nabla$, the defining equation for the field strength $F_{\nabla}$ would looks like this:
$$
d_{\nabla}d_{\nabla}\phi=F_{\nabla}\phi
$$
for all section $\phi \in \Gamma(E)$.

Comment: Okay this definitely helps. I guess my main question is why the commutator? I.e. why does the commutator of the covariant derivatives give the associated gauge field strength? Is it just a definition, or is there more to it?

Comment: It is a matter of definition, you are basically seeing that the commutator of two covariant derivatives (seen as operators) is just applying the curvature tensor.
I think its a nice way to measure how the de Rham cohomology fails. Notice that on a flat vector bundles, vector bundles where $F_{\nabla}=0$.